# Ошибка при запуске программы android

Tags: android

Всем привет имеется вот такая ошибка

> **The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml**

Мол я свою активити никак не записал в манифест.
Окей иду в манифест

Вижу это:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Вродебы все записано.
Знающие люди подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю что вам поможет два варианта:

```
File->Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

либо перезагрузка с очисткой кэша:

```
File->Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Comment: не знаю как это объяснить, но я пробовал эти 2 варианта ещё в самом начале когда у меня началась эта ошибка, а это примерно 2 часа назад и оно не помогало и тут все сработало, магия какая-то)
Спасибо)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него

Comment: Если эта "магия" не помогает, то закрыть студию, и удалить директории: `.idea/chachelibrary` и `app/.gradle/*` - названия писал по памяти, возможно ошибся в буквах.

Comment: @ClonOffTimer, в целом магия должна помочь, но все-равно спасибо за уточнение :)